# Month name to value in Julia?

Tags: julia

I need to convert a peculiar format of textual dates into dates in Julia. I found out about the `MONTHTOVALUE` dictionary in the [Dates documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/dates/), but this object is missing from the `Dates` namespace, gives no results in the help, and only appears in the [Github source code in the documentation](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/search?q=monthtovalue&unscoped_q=monthtovalue). I used `Date.format()` with formatting `"U"` to define my own `MONTHTOVALUE`:

```
  # Build dictionary from month names to integers
  MONTHTOVALUE = Dict{String, Integer}()
  for i in 1:12
      month = Dates.format(Date(1990, i, 1), "U")
      MONTHTOVALUE[month] = i
  end;

  # Regular expression for date in the format [Month Year(Quarter)]
  date_regex = r"(^[A-Z][a-z]*) ?(\d{4}) ?\((I*V?)\)";
  function string_to_date(date_string)
      month = MONTHTOVALUE[replace(date_string, date_regex, s"\1")]
      year = parse(Int, replace(date_string, date_regex, s"\2"))
      return Dates.Date(year, month, 1)
  end;
  @assert Dates.Date(1860, 10, 1) == string_to_date("October 1860(III)")
```

Does the `MONTHTOVALUE` dictionary exist already, or do you suggest a cleaner way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you wish to access the dictionary inside the `Dates` module that maps month names to their number ("March"=>3, etc.), is that correct?

If so, `Dates.LOCALES["english"].month_value` seems to be the one you're looking for:

```
julia> Dates.LOCALES["english"].month_value
Dict{String,Int64} with 24 entries:
  "January"   => 1
  "august"    => 8
  "May"       => 5
  "may"       => 5
  "December"  => 12
  "january"   => 1
  "August"    => 8
  "november"  => 11
  "december"  => 12
  "September" => 9
  "july"      => 7
  "september" => 9
  "October"   => 10
  "june"      => 6
  "November"  => 11
  "April"     => 4
  "February"  => 2
  "october"   => 10
  "March"     => 3
  "June"      => 6
  "april"     => 4
  "march"     => 3
  "february"  => 2
  "July"      => 7
```

(There's also a `Dates.LOCALES["english"].month_abbr_value` if you need it.)

I'm guessing that part of the documentation is outdated, and `MONTHTOVALUE` used to be `month_value` dict's older name.

There's also the function `Dates.monthname_to_value`, used like `Dates.monthname_to_value("September",Dates.LOCALES["english"])`, providing an interface into the above dict.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to access that dictionary that mapped month names to number. I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've not heard of Julia, but passage seems relevant:

> Support for text-form month parsing is also supported through the u
>   and U characters, for abbreviated and full-length month names,
>   respectively. By default, only English month names are supported, so u
>   corresponds to "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", etc. And U corresponds to
>   "January", "February", "March", etc. Similar to other name=>value
>   mapping functions dayname() and monthname(), custom locales can be
>   loaded by passing in the locale=>Dict{String,Int} mapping to the
>   MONTHTOVALUEABBR and MONTHTOVALUE dicts for abbreviated and full-name
>   month names, respectively.

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6.2/manual/dates/

Edit: I think you can make the dictionary like this:

```
monthtovalue = Dict{UTF8String, Int}()
for (value, name) in VALUETOMONTH[locale::AbstractString="english"]
    monthtovalue[lowercase(name)] = value
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that is the passage I read in the documentation, but nowhere can I find `MONTHTOVALUE`. Your code gives me an error: `UndefVarError: VALUETOMONTH not defined`.